# Compressing a PDF's images using Python (help replacing images inside a PDF)

Tags: python, pdf, image-compression

My goal is to have a Python script that will take a PDF, extract its images, compress/resize them, and then push this new data to the PDF which will result in a new, smaller PDF.

So far I have done everything except replace the image data with the correct counterpart. I find the correct place where the image data is located (between the "stream" and "streamend" tags).

Here is my code (updated):

```
def crunchPdfImages(file_to_crunch, max_width=1200, max_height=628):
    page_ratio = max_width / max_height
    working_folder = os.path.dirname(file_to_crunch)
    working_dir = os.path.join(working_folder, "temp_working_dir")
    if not (os.path.exists(working_dir)): os.mkdir(working_dir)
    
    # Get all the image...
    extractPDFImages(file_to_crunch, working_dir)
    # Compress all the images... (no resize)
    all_image_list = [entry.path for entry in os.scandir(working_dir) if isImage(entry.path)]
    for an_image in all_image_list:
        img_picture = Image.open(an_image).convert("RGB")
        img_picture.save(an_image, "JPEG", optimize=True)
    
    # Uncompress the PDF
    pdf_folder = os.path.join(working_dir, "pdf_uncompressed")
    if not (os.path.exists(pdf_folder)): os.mkdir(pdf_folder)
    pdf_datain_file = os.path.join(pdf_folder, "uncompressed_pdf.pdf")
    pdf_dataout_file = os.path.join(pdf_folder, "new_images_pdf.pdf")
    pypdftk.uncompress('"' + file_to_crunch + '"', pdf_datain_file)
    
    # Now get to work...
    #   The PDF is comprised of objects, some of which are lablled as images.
    #   Each image has the line "/Subtype /Image" before the "stream" which is then ended by "endstream" then "endobj".
    #   In between the stream and endstream is the encoded image data... hopefully I can replace this in the same order that
    #   the images were taken out.
    picture_replace_count = 0
    pdf_openfile_in = open(pdf_datain_file, "rb")
    pdf_openfile_out = open(pdf_dataout_file, "wb")
    pdf_file_lines = pdf_openfile_in.readlines()
    
    looking_for_next_stream = False
    found_stream_and_removing = False
    updating_xref_stage = 0
    skip_a_line = False
    
    for line in pdf_file_lines:
        new_line_addition = "" # For adding to byte count, resetting to null here just in case
        current_line_val = line.decode("Latin-1").strip()
        
        if (looking_for_next_stream):
            # Last image tag has been found but not dealt with, so find the stream then
            if (current_line_val[:8] == "/Length "):
                # Update the length
                skip_a_line = True
                new_img_size = str(os.path.getsize(all_image_list[picture_replace_count]))
                new_line = r"/Length " + new_img_size + "\n"
                pdf_openfile_out.write(new_line.encode("latin-1")) # add new line
            if (current_line_val == "stream"):
                print("Stream start found... skipping stream information")
                looking_for_next_stream = False # it's been found
                found_stream_and_removing = True # time to delete
                
                new_line_addition = "stream\n".encode("latin-1")
                pdf_openfile_out.write(new_line_addition) # add the line in or it will be skipped
                
        elif (found_stream_and_removing):
            if (current_line_val == "endstream"):
                print("Stream end found")
                found_stream_and_removing = False # Passed through all image data line
                # Now, add in the new image data and continue on.
                print("Adding new image data...")
                #new_image_file = open(all_image_list[picture_replace_count], "rb")
                img = Image.open(all_image_list[picture_replace_count], mode='r')
                img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
                img.save(img_byte_arr, format='JPEG')
                img_byte_arr = img_byte_arr.getvalue()
                
                pdf_openfile_out.write(img_byte_arr)
                new_line_addition = img_byte_arr
                """
                for imgline in new_image_file.readlines():
                    #pdf_openfile_out.write(imgline.encode("Latin-1"))
                    #pdf_openfile_out.write(imgline)
                    pass
                #pdf_openfile_out.write("[IMAGEADD]".encode("latin-1")) # add new line
                """
                #new_image_file.close()
                picture_replace_count += 1
                print("New image added.")
                pdf_openfile_out.write("\n".encode("latin-1")) # add new line
                
                if (picture_replace_count >= len(all_image_list)):
                    updating_xref_stage = 1 # All images replaced, now edit the xref.
                    
        elif (current_line_val == r"/Subtype /Image"):
            print("Found an image place, number " + str(picture_replace_count))
            print("Looking for stream start...")
            looking_for_next_stream = True
            # Find next 
        
        if not (found_stream_and_removing) and not (skip_a_line) and not (updating_xref_stage == 4): 
            pdf_openfile_out.write(line)
        
        skip_a_line = False
        

    pdf_openfile_in.close()
    pdf_openfile_out.close()
    
    print("Rebuilding xref table (post newfile creation)")
    rebuildXrefTable(pdf_dataout_file)
```

And to rebuild the xref table (as per a comment here) I run the following function. I did try to do it within the previous function, but the data ended up being outputted at a different size. I haven't worked out how to accurately push the photo date into the PDF stream.

```
def rebuildXrefTable(pdf_file_in, pdf_file_out=None):
    # Updating the xref table:
    #   * Assumes uncompressed PDF file
    #   To do this I need the number of bytes that precede and object (this is used as a reference).
    #   So, each line I will need to count the byte number and tally up
    #   When an object is found, the byte_count will be added to the reference list and then used to create the xref table
    #   Also need to update the "startxref" at the bottom (similar principle).
    
    if (pdf_file_out == None): pdf_file_out = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(pdf_file_in), "rebuilt_xref_pdf.pdf")
    print("Updating xref table of: " + os.path.basename(pdf_file_in))
    
    byte_count = 0
    xref_start = 0
    object_location_reference = []
    updating_xref_stage = 1
    pdf_openfile_in = open(pdf_file_in, "rb")
    pdf_openfile_out = open(pdf_file_out, "wb")
    pdf_file_lines = pdf_openfile_in.readlines()
    
    for line in pdf_file_lines:
        current_line_val = line.decode("Latin-1").strip()
        if (" obj" in current_line_val):
            # Check if the place is an object loc, store byte reference and object index
            obj_ref_index = current_line_val.split(" ")[0]
            print("Found new object (index, location): (" + str(obj_ref_index) + ", " + str(byte_count) + ")")
            object_location_reference.append((int(obj_ref_index), byte_count))
        elif ("startxref" in current_line_val):
            # This is the last thing to edit (right at the bottom, update the xref start location and then add the file end.
            print("Updating the xref start value with new data...")
            new_line = "startxref\n" + str(xref_start) + "\n" + r"%%EOF"
            pdf_openfile_out.write(new_line.encode("latin-1"))
            break
        elif ("xref" in current_line_val):
            print("Recording the new xref byte location")
            preceeding_str = current_line_val.split("xref")[0]
            preceeding_count = len(preceeding_str.encode("latin-1"))
            xref_start = byte_count + preceeding_count # used at the end
            updating_xref_stage = 2 
        
        elif (updating_xref_stage == 2 or updating_xref_stage == 3): 
            # This stage simply skips the first 2 xref data lines (and prints it o the new file as is)
            updating_xref_stage += 1
        elif (updating_xref_stage == 4):
            print("Creating new xref object byte location table...")
            object_location_reference.sort() # Sort the collected xref locations by their object index.
            # Now add the new xref data information
            for xref_loc in object_location_reference:
                new_val = str(xref_loc[1]).zfill(10) # Pad the number out
                new_val = new_val + " 00000 n \n"
                pdf_openfile_out.write(new_val.encode("latin-1"))
            updating_xref_stage = 5
        elif (updating_xref_stage == 5):
            # Stage 5 doesn't record the read in lines into new file
            if ("trailer" in current_line_val): updating_xref_stage = 5
        
        # Write to file
        if not (updating_xref_stage == 5):
            pdf_openfile_out.write(line)
            byte_count += len(line)
    
    pdf_openfile_in.close()
    pdf_openfile_out.close()
```

The xref table is accurate and points to the right byte-location, I also made sure it was in the proper order (using the object index number, not the order it appears in the file--this matches the original PDF document).

If I don't try to replace anything and just spit out the data into the new PDF file, it works and I can open the new file. However, when the replacement JPG data is inserted the PDF can't open because it is broken.

I don't know how to push the right data to the PDF file from the compressed images.

I have also tried to simply push the JPG data like this:

```
image = open(all_image_list[picture_replace_count], 'rb')
pdf_openfile_out.write(image.read())
image.close()
```

Using: Python 3.8

Comment: In the PDF format there is a data structure called the xref table that contains offsets to all the objects in the file. You'll need to update that to reflect the new image sizes.

Comment: You treat the PDF as if it were a text file. That is only partially the case. In particular the content of streams have to be treated as binary data, in particular not read and written like text lines. Furthermore, you don't adapt the image dictionaries to your image change. In particular images that used to be in a different format and now have become jpegs have incorrect entries there.

Comment: I was figuring that the PDF would display the new image stream data using the same dimensions as the previous data. I believed it would work but display the new image skewed, which I had planned to fix after the fact.

I will try to update the xref table / image dictionary data and change my method of copying the image data (not line by line, but as one big piece of data) and see if this helps.

Comment: I have now updated my code (and edited the original question to reflect it). I rebuilt the xref table so that it correctly points to the objects. I also have updated the "/length" property to reflect the size of the photos and now keep the height and width the same as the original images. I tried to get the JPG data across, but have failed. I'm not sure how to replicate the JPG data accurately.

Comment: Have you run a file without images through your code and compared the result to the uncompressed intermediary? They should be identical. Are they?

Comment: Oh my goodness, it was working... I had modified my code to rebuild the xref table in stages (using the "updating_xref_stage" variable) and added a new stage... at the end I didn't +1 to the last stage, so the very end of the file was not reproduced.

mkl's comment made me double-check the output without images and I found the error.

My test went from 17.5MB to 3.8MB and opens without error. I will paste the code as a new answer. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments here, I have resolved the issue. The xref table had to be rebuilt, and the JPG data placed in as a whole. Here is the working code:

```
import os
import pypdftk # pdftk main prog has to be installed and added to path too...
import pdf2image
from PIL import Image

def crunchPdfImages(file_to_crunch):
    working_folder = os.path.dirname(file_to_crunch)
    working_dir = os.path.join(working_folder, "temp_working_dir")
    if not (os.path.exists(working_dir)): os.mkdir(working_dir)
    
    # Get all the image...
    extractPDFImages(file_to_crunch, working_dir)
    # Compress all the images... (no resize, just optimise)
    all_image_list = [entry.path for entry in os.scandir(working_dir) if isImage(entry.path)]
    if (len(all_image_list) > 0):
        for an_image in all_image_list:
            img_picture = Image.open(an_image).convert("RGB")
            img_picture.save(an_image, "JPEG", optimize=True)
    else:
        print("No images found in PDF...")
    
    # Uncompress the PDF
    pdf_folder = os.path.join(working_dir, "pdf_uncompressed")
    if not (os.path.exists(pdf_folder)): os.mkdir(pdf_folder)
    pdf_datain_file = os.path.join(pdf_folder, "uncompressed_pdf.pdf")
    pdf_dataout_file = os.path.join(pdf_folder, "new_images_pdf.pdf")
    print("Uncompressing PDF...")
    pypdftk.uncompress('"' + file_to_crunch + '"', '"' + pdf_datain_file + '"')
    
    # Now get to work...
    #   The PDF is comprised of objects, some of which are lablled as images.
    #   Each image has the line "/Subtype /Image" before the "stream" which is then ended by "endstream" then "endobj".
    #   In between the stream and endstream is the encoded image data... hopefully I can replace this in the same order that
    #   the images were taken out.
    picture_replace_count = 0
    pdf_openfile_in = open(pdf_datain_file, "rb")
    pdf_openfile_out = open(pdf_dataout_file, "wb")
    pdf_file_lines = pdf_openfile_in.readlines()
    
    looking_for_next_stream = False
    found_stream_and_removing = False
    skip_a_line = False
    
    for line in pdf_file_lines:
        new_line_addition = "" # For adding to byte count, resetting to null here just in case
        current_line_val = line.decode("Latin-1").strip()
        
        if (looking_for_next_stream):
            # Last image tag has been found but not dealt with, so find the stream then
            if (current_line_val[:8] == "/Length "):
                # Update the length
                skip_a_line = True
                new_img_size = str(os.path.getsize(all_image_list[picture_replace_count]))
                new_line = r"/Length " + new_img_size + "\n"
                pdf_openfile_out.write(new_line.encode("latin-1")) # add new line
            if (current_line_val == "stream"):
                print("Stream start found... skipping stream information")
                looking_for_next_stream = False # it's been found
                found_stream_and_removing = True # time to delete
                
                new_line_addition = "stream\n".encode("latin-1")
                pdf_openfile_out.write(new_line_addition) # add the line in or it will be skipped
                
        elif (found_stream_and_removing):
            if (current_line_val == "endstream"):
                print("Stream end found")
                found_stream_and_removing = False # Passed through all image data line
                # Now, add in the new image data and continue on.
                print("Adding new image data...")
                
                image = open(all_image_list[picture_replace_count], 'rb')
                pdf_openfile_out.write(image.read())
                image.close()
                
                picture_replace_count += 1
                pdf_openfile_out.write("\n".encode("latin-1")) # add new line
                    
        elif (current_line_val == r"/Subtype /Image"):
            print("Found an image place, number " + str(picture_replace_count))
            print("Looking for stream start...")
            looking_for_next_stream = True
            # Find next 
        
        if not (found_stream_and_removing) and not (skip_a_line): 
            pdf_openfile_out.write(line)
        
        skip_a_line = False

    pdf_openfile_in.close()
    pdf_openfile_out.close()
    
    print("Rebuilding xref table (post newfile creation)")
    rebuildXrefTable(pdf_dataout_file)

def rebuildXrefTable(pdf_file_in, pdf_file_out=None):
    # Updating the xref table:
    #   * Assumes uncompressed PDF file
    #   To do this I need the number of bytes that precede and object (this is used as a reference).
    #   So, each line I will need to count the byte number and tally up
    #   When an object is found, the byte_count will be added to the reference list and then used to create the xref table
    #   Also need to update the "startxref" at the bottom (similar principle).
    
    if (pdf_file_out == None): pdf_file_out = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(pdf_file_in), "rebuilt_xref_pdf.pdf")
    print("Updating xref table of: " + os.path.basename(pdf_file_in))
    
    byte_count = 0
    xref_start = 0
    object_location_reference = []
    updating_xref_stage = 1
    pdf_openfile_in = open(pdf_file_in, "rb")
    pdf_openfile_out = open(pdf_file_out, "wb")
    pdf_file_lines = pdf_openfile_in.readlines()
    
    for line in pdf_file_lines:
        current_line_val = line.decode("Latin-1").strip()
        if (" obj" in current_line_val):
            # Check if the place is an object loc, store byte reference and object index
            obj_ref_index = current_line_val.split(" ")[0]
            print("Found new object (index, location): (" + str(obj_ref_index) + ", " + str(byte_count) + ")")
            object_location_reference.append((int(obj_ref_index), byte_count))
        elif ("startxref" in current_line_val):
            # This is the last thing to edit (right at the bottom, update the xref start location and then add the file end.
            print("Updating the xref start value with new data...")
            new_line = "startxref\n" + str(xref_start) + "\n" + r"%%EOF"
            pdf_openfile_out.write(new_line.encode("latin-1"))
            break
        elif ("xref" in current_line_val):
            print("Recording the new xref byte location")
            preceeding_str = current_line_val.split("xref")[0]
            preceeding_count = len(preceeding_str.encode("latin-1"))
            xref_start = byte_count + preceeding_count # used at the end
            updating_xref_stage = 2 
        
        elif (updating_xref_stage == 2 or updating_xref_stage == 3): 
            # This stage simply skips the first 2 xref data lines (and prints it o the new file as is)
            updating_xref_stage += 1
        elif (updating_xref_stage == 4):
            print("Creating new xref object byte location table...")
            object_location_reference.sort() # Sort the collected xref locations by their object index.
            # Now add the new xref data information
            for xref_loc in object_location_reference:
                new_val = str(xref_loc[1]).zfill(10) # Pad the number out
                new_val = new_val + " 00000 n \n"
                pdf_openfile_out.write(new_val.encode("latin-1"))
            updating_xref_stage = 5
        elif (updating_xref_stage == 5):
            # Stage 5 doesn't record the read in lines into new file, step 6 will.
            if ("trailer" in current_line_val): updating_xref_stage = 6
        
        # Write to file
        if not (updating_xref_stage == 5):
            pdf_openfile_out.write(line)
            byte_count += len(line)
    
    pdf_openfile_in.close()
    pdf_openfile_out.close()

# To use the PDF compression:
crunchPdfImages(r"C:\Users\Person\Desktop\Test Folder\Pdf File.pdf")
```

Comment: it's not the whole code, which imports do u use?

Comment: @DemetryPascal I've edited the answer with the relevant imports. extractPDFImages() is a custom function that uses pdf2img to extract the images from the PDF.

Comment: @Kane Does your codes includes the full compression of PDF or just the correct placing of images to a new PDF?

Comment: @Ejardy It only deals with images.